# How do I enter a url link using jsoup

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I made 2 simple html pages

page1:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <a href="page2.html">enter page 2</a>
 <p>
    some data
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

page2:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <a href="page1.html">enter page 1</a>
   <a href="page3.html">enter page 3</a>
 <p>
    some other data
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the links using jsoup library

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/"); //file = page1.html
Element link = doc.select("a").first();
String absHref = link.attr("href"); // "page2.html/"
```

now what I want to do, is to enter page 2 from page 1(its localy on my computer), and parse it.

I tried to do this:

```
Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(absHref).get();
```

But it dosent work, doing me the 404 eror

EDIT:

From a small replay by @JonasCz I tried this: and it is working, I just think there is a better and smarter way.

```
File file = new File(args[0]);
String path = file.getParent() + "\\";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/"); //file = page1.html
Element link = doc.select("a").first();
String Href = link.attr("href"); // "page2.html/"
File file2 = new File(path+href);
Document doc2 = Jsoup.parse(file2, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
```

Thank you

Comment: You can create Set of absolute hrefs and parse/visit only those which you can still add to set.

Answer (score 1):

You are going the right way but you are not creating absolute URL.

Instead of:

```
String absHref = link.attr("href"); // "page2.html/"
```

Use
:

```
String absHref = link.absUrl("href"); // this wil give you http://example.com/page2.html
```

The rest is just as you are doing.

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html

Unfortunetly, Jsoup is not a web crawler, but only parser with the ability to directly connect and fetch pages. Crawling logic - eg. what to fetch/visit next is on your responsibility to implement. You could google for web crawlers for Java, maybe something else would be more suitable.

Comment: I dont agree with you, I think you can make a small web crawler with it with a little recursion function.
http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-using-java/

Comment: For OP: If you want to get an absolute URL to your actual second HTML file, you will need to specify your the path of your local HTML file instead of `example.com` as your base URL when parsing, else this won't work as expected.

Comment: JonasCZ, I tried that, it is working great. but I am sure there is a smarter way....

Comment: @Yogi_Bear, Re your first comment: Sure, but it's easier to use something that already exists (eg. Crawler4J) instead of writing your own.

Comment: @Yogi_Bear You dont agree with me in which part?? If you do it with recursion - you are implementin it on your own. Is it not what my answer states? Anyway, do whatever you want, after all reinventing the wheel is not that bad.

Comment: @Antoniossss Hi man, dont get upset...Just a missunderstanding, I thought you meant its impossible